# Why am I getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, compiler-errors

I have two other buttons with almost the exact same code. However I get the error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" when I try to run this code to fetch all the results.

The show invalid NHS numbers button works but I can't see why this works but the show all records button does not. The error is in the dgvResults section of the lower block of code, but not the first.

```
 private void cmdShowInvalidNHSnumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string databaseFilename;
        string sql;

        dgvResults.ColumnCount = 3;
        dgvResults.Columns[0].Name = "NHSNumber";
        dgvResults.Columns[1].Name = "Patient";
        dgvResults.Columns[2].Name = "Problem";

        dgvResults.Rows.Clear();

        databaseFilename = Application.StartupPath + "\\nhsnumberchecker.db";

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseFilename + ";Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();

        sql = @"
        SELECT * FROM results
        -- WHERE NHSNumber = 'N'
        WHERE NHSNumberValid = 'N'
        ORDER BY Surname;";

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dgvResults.Rows.Add(reader["NHSNumber"], reader["Surname"] + ", " + reader["GivenName"], NHSnumberError(reader.GetString(0)));
        }

        dgvResults.Refresh();
        dgvResults.AutoResizeColumns();
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }







 private void cmdShowAllResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string databaseFilename;
        string sql;

        dgvResults.ColumnCount = 7;
        dgvResults.Columns[0].Name = "NHSNumber";
        dgvResults.Columns[1].Name = "DOB";
        dgvResults.Columns[2].Name = "Title";
        dgvResults.Columns[3].Name = "Surname";
        dgvResults.Columns[4].Name = "GivenName";
        dgvResults.Columns[5].Name = "Gender";
        dgvResults.Columns[6].Name = "Problem";

        dgvResults.Rows.Clear();

        databaseFilename = Application.StartupPath + "\\nhsnumberchecker.db";

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseFilename + ";Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();

        sql = @"
        SELECT * FROM results
        ORDER BY Surname;";

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dgvResults.Rows.Add(reader["NHSNumber"], reader["DOB"], reader["Title"], reader["Surname"] + ", " + reader["GivenName"],
                reader["Gender"], reader["Problem"], NHSnumberError(reader.GetString(0))); //This section is causing the error
        }

        dgvResults.Refresh();
        dgvResults.AutoResizeColumns();
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

The lower section of code is the one that gets the error message. I don't understand what part of it is "out of range".

Comment: Which line raises the exception?

Comment: The error is in the dgvResults section of the lower block of code where I am adding in the rows

Comment: Add a comment to the code showing the exact line raising the exception

Comment: Clearly, you are getting fewer values from the SQL query, and when you try to access them they are not there. Try using a simple `Message.Box(string)` and looping through your array.

Comment: While debuging just check what columns your reader contains and compare what are you trying to get from it. Something does not match

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that your query results contains a "," character.
Try to modify all your entries adding a replace method to see if that is true:

```
dgvResults.Rows.Add(reader["NHSNumber"].Replace("," , "") , ............
```